# Inserting Node at given position

Tags: python, linked-list

I am learning python and data structure. I was implementing singly linked list methods which included inserting at head and at given position. I ended up writing this code :

```
class Node :
    def __init__(self,data=None,next_node=None) :
        self.data = data
        self.next = next_node

class LinkedList :
    def __init__(self) :
        self.head = None

    def insertathead(self,new_data) :
        new_node = Node(new_data)
        new_node.next = self.head
        self.head = new_node


    def InsertNpos(self,new_data,pos):
        start = self.head
        if pos == 0:
            return Node(new_data, self.head)
        while pos > 1:
            self.head = self.head.next
            pos -= 1
        self.head.next = Node(new_data, self.head.next)
        return start

    def PrintLinkList(self) :
        temp = self.head
        while (temp) :
            print (temp.data)
            temp = temp.next

if __name__ == '__main__' :
   llist = LinkedList()
   llist.insertathead(8)
   llist.insertathead(3)     
   llist.insertathead(10)
   llist.insertathead(12)
   llist.insertathead(15)
   llist.insertathead(2)
   llist.InsertNpos(1,2)
   llist.PrintLinkList()
```

Output:

```
 15
 1
 12
 10
 3
 8
```

Now, just inserting at head works fine but InsertNpos(1,2) gives wrong output. The output is supposed to be 2,15,1,12,10,3,8.Please tell me where my code is wrong.

Comment: What is the wrong output?  I see a node valued 1 at position 2 ... or does your numbering start at 0?  We need to have a clear description of what you expected to happen, and why.

Comment: When you say 'gives wrong output', please specify what the output is supposed to be.

Comment: You are using `self.head` in `InsertNpos()` to iterate through the linked list, which means you lose the real `head`. I think `self.head = start` may be the simple fix but you probably just want to use `start` to iterate through the list. Even in the base case insert at `0` does not update `self.head`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you insert at position **pos**, your insertion routine *deletes* the first **pos-1** elements of the list.  It *changes* the head pointer on each iteration.  You need a local variable to iterate through the list.  Also, why are you returning a value?  You never use it.  The only purpose of this method is to update the list in place.

```
def InsertNpos(self,new_data,pos):
    if pos == 0:
        self.head = Node(new_data, self.head)
        return

    start = self.head
    while pos > 1:
        start = start.next
        pos -= 1
    start.next = Node(new_data, start.next)
```

New output:

```
Before insertion
2
15
12
10
3
8
After  insertion
2
15
1
12
10
3
8
```

Comment: Looks like a cut&paste error... does this handle the base case insert @ `0` - `if pos == 0: self.head = Node(..., self.head); return`

Comment: @AChampion@prune Thank you guys for explaining.

Comment: @Prune, no problem - was tempted to add error handling (`try: ... except AttributeError: break`) to cover `pos > length` but that seemed beyond the OP's ask.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the answer has already been accepted, I tried the solution and as AChampion suggested it didn't work for me for inserting at 0, but my solution did:

```
class Node :
    def __init__(self,data=None,next_node=None) :
        self.data = data
        self.next = next_node

class LinkedList :
    def __init__(self) :
        self.head = None

    def insertathead(self,new_data) :
        new_node = Node(new_data)
        new_node.next = self.head
        self.head = new_node


    def InsertNpos(self,new_data,pos):
        if pos == 0:
            self.head = Node(new_data, self.head)
            return self.head
        i = 0
        curr = self.head
        while curr.next:
            if i == pos - 1:
                curr.next = Node(new_data, curr.next)
                return self.head
            curr = curr.next
            i += 1
        curr.next = Node(new_data)
        return self.head

    def PrintLinkList(self) :
        temp = self.head
        while (temp) :
            print (temp.data)
            temp = temp.next
```

This will insert the item at the end if `pos` is out of range.

Answer (score 0):

```
def insertNodeAtPosition(head, data, position):
    current = head
    if not head:
        head = SinglyLinkedListNode(data)
        return head

    # Shift to element before position i.e. before_node
    # Change it to point to new_node
    # Set new_node.next to before_node.next
    for _ in range(position-1):
        current = current.next

    temp = current.next
    new_node = SinglyLinkedListNode(data)
    current.next = new_node
    new_node.next = temp

    return head
```